# Windows 10: Most efficient way of getting around "The library, drive, or medial pool is empty" errors while copying photos from Android?

Tags: windows-10, usb, android, file-transfer, photos

I have a Google Nexus 5.  The camera app seems to like to generate corrupted jpg files.  Maybe 1-2% of the files seem to be corrupted.

Usually I wait several months before transferring the photos to my computer.  Then I plug in my USB cable, make a new folder on Windows 10, and drag drop the entire contents of the `/DCIM/Camera` folder into my newly created folder.  In the process I often run into this annoying popup.

[image]

I don't actually care about the corrupted images, I have no desire to try to recover them.  What I would like to do is just copy all of the files which are not corrupted.  This popup makes that difficult because

1) It does not tell you which file is corrupt.  If it did I would be able to go and delete the offending file from the android `DCIM` folder and go on with my life

2) It aborts the copying process, leaving me with a folder that contains a subset of the contents of the source folder.

In the past, I have worked around this with a tedious process of copying small batches of files from the source directory, deleting when the copy succeeds.  If it fails, I try a smaller batch until I figure out which file is the problematic one.

In the USB transfer options that are present on Android, I have tried both "File Transfers" (MTP) and "Photo Transfers" (PTP) and both exhibit the same problem.

I would love it if there's a way to disable this dialog and make Windows 10 just continue on with the copy.  If there was a command line way of doing the copy which does not abort, that would be great.  But I have researched in to mounting the Android device as a drive letter and that seems difficult to do.

I'm not interested in enabling cloud storage of my photos, I'm looking for a direct USB file transfer solution.

I'm looking for a solution to one of the following problems

- Alternative, simple, methods of transferring the files over USB which might get around the problem
- A quick way of determining which photos are corrupted and deleting them so that the problem does not occur upon file transfer

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question with another workaround, though I don't really consider this a great answer:

I have been using an app called File Manager on Android which supports Network folders.  In this way i can upload to a network attached stored (NAS) and then copy from there to my Windows 10 PC

I don't consider this a great solution because

- The file transfer is over Wifi, not USB, so not as fast
- I'm limited in where I can transfer it to because the desired destination folder is not a networked folder
- Since I only have my NAS exposed as network storage it means having to transfer the files over wifi twice (phone->NAS, NAS->PC)
- It's an overly technical solution, I feel like a good answer to this questions should work for someone who is less technical than me.

Comment: A similar option is to use FTP, which is supported by many file explorers on android: set up the "server" on the app, then open explorer with the given address (ex.: ftp://192.168.0.5:2000)